# How to extract multiple lines of data from a form field and insert in to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I wonder if anyone can help. I'm new with PHP code so please bear with me. I have copied multiple Lines of the charts from a word doc into a text area field. Similar to the following...

```
Pos Last Week   WOC Move    Artist  Title

1   1   4   NM  One Direction   Drag me Down

2   4   5   +1  John Newman Come & Get It

3   NE  1   NE  Elle King   Ex's and Oh's

4   3   3   -1  Demi Lovato Cool for the Summer

5   2   2   -3  Example Whisky Story
```

On my page the data copied into the txt field looks like the following...

```
1

1

4

NM

One Direction

Drag me Down


2
4
5
+1
John Newman
Come & Get It
3
NE
1
NE
Elle King
Ex's and Oh's
```

What I want to do is grab each line of data and store it in a relevant variable then when all the variables contain the details for the first song, it inserts it into the database. This continues until all the songs of the top 40 have been added to the database. The reason for this is that it would cut out, the excel spreadsheet process and then the importing into mysql.

Any ideas would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you export the excel sheet as a csv? I see no easy way to parse the data your currently have. You could try to rig up some hacky regex but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: That is what is being done at the moment, but they want to avoid this process so that non technical users can update the charts using the latest information from chart data suppliers.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work assuming there are fixed number of values for each row. Like if there is a row with 3 values and one with 4 values, this code will not work.. In that case you can use the 'id field' instead of the remainder comparison.

Untested:

```
$row = array() ;
$lines = file('file.txt') ;
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= count($lines);$i++){
    if (trim($lines[$i])){ // if not blank
        $row[] = $lines[$i] ;
        if ($i % 6 === 0 ){ //every 6th row
            insert_to_db($row) ; // or export to csv or whatever  
            $row = array() ; //reset array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I explained incorrectly but their is no text file involved. Data is copied from a work doc always 6 bits of data, to be pasted into a text form field and the rest of the work needs to be done by php to separate each piece of data and then insert those 6 pieces of data into a record set.

Comment: Just send a POST request with the textarea data to a PHP URL and use the above.  You just need the $lines array to be populated with textarea data.

Comment: Hi I can sent a post request but am not sure how i would implement you code. Sorry for being stupid. ;)

Comment: I use dreamwweaver to create the text field and I have added test text data into field like so

Comment: <label for="newcharts"></label>
          <textarea name="newcharts" id="newcharts" cols="80" rows="10">1 1 4 NM One Direction Drag me Down
2 4 5 +1 John Newman Come & Get It
3 NE 1 NE Elle King Ex's and Oh's
4 3 3 -1 Demi Lovato Cool for the Summer
5 2 2 -3 Example Whisky Story
6 6 3 NM Maroon5 Feelings
7 9 4 +2 Disclosure feat Sam Smith Omen
8 7 10 -1 Rita Ora Poison
9 5 6 -4 Pharrell Williams Freedom
10 8 7 -2 Giorgio Moroder ft. Sia Deja Vu
        </textarea>